# getpwuid error with screen command for chroot user

Tags: bash, permissions, ssh, screen, chroot

The background is that I want to allow a chrooted user to execute a shell script in a detatched screen.

I created a chroot user and gave him a home directory. In this directory I made a `/bin` directory, copied `bash` and some other files like `ls, cd, id` and also `screen` into it.

After that I listed required libraries for every command with

e.g. `ldd /bin/bash`

and copied them all to their appropriate directorys under the chroot `/home/userdirectory`.

Logging in over an ssh client and every command works, except for `screen` the user gets the error:

`getpwuid() cant't identify your account!`

I tried to copy the standard `/etc/profile` to the users home directory, also the `/etc/passwd`. It doesn't make muche sense, but I tried, but this didn't help. The `/etc/passwd` is executed and works, but it only sets the `$PS1` and checks `/etc/profile.d` for entrys as far as I understand.

The error comes from the screen command. I'm sure about that since I checked the executable for the string. What am I missing here?